# choice of local system in Deligne's construction of $l$-adic Galois representations

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, nt.number-theory, shimura-varieties, galois-representations

Hello,

Deligne famously constructed $l$-adic representations of $G_\mathbf Q = Gal(\overline{\mathbf Q}/\mathbf Q)$ starting form cusp modular forms of weight $k$ by looking inside the cohomology group $H^1_{et}(M_n, Sym^k R^1f_{n*}\mathbf Q_l)$,
where $M_n$ is the moduli space of elliptic curves with full level-$n$ structure and $f_n: E_n\to M_n$ is the universal elliptic curve.

Question 1: How did Deligne know that he had to look at $Sym^k R^1f_{n*}\mathbf Q_l$ and not something else?

Question 2: What happens if one chooses some other local system (which is suitably invariant under $GL_2$). Is it possible to say anything about the resulting Galois representation?

Thanks

Comment: Q1 one answer is that the Eichler-Shimura isomorphism, or some standard Hodge--de Rham spectral sequence, relates modular forms to this cohomology group. In fact you can really compute the space with its Hecke action (_not_ its Galois action) using entirely transcendental methods and just see the modular forms coming out. Q2 the answer is I guess that up to twist $Symm^k$ are the only representations of $GL(2)$ so it's really hard to imagine any other possibilities other than the ones Deligne uses. Forget about etale cohomology and think about it from the...


Comment: ...point of view of complex geometry. These sheaves that Deligne uses are just all the sheaves coming from all the algebraic representations of $GL(2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin. Do you know where can I find the transcendental computation that you mention in your comment (i.e. where can I find a proof of the Eichler-Shimura isomorphism, which is only quoted in Deligne's paper)?

Comment: I learnt it from Shimura's book. I'm not sure I'd recommend that to you though :-( I don't remember it being in Miyake. Is it in Diamond-Shurman? Let me stick to weight 2. You're asking what relationship there is between $H^1_et(Y(\Gamma),Q_\ell)$ and weight 2 modular forms for $\Gamma$. But there's this standard map from $H^0(\Omega^1)$ (coherent coh) to $H^1(\mathbf{C})$ (singular coh) given by integration -- that's Eichler-Shimura in the weight 2 case. Maybe Shimura's book is the best place to read about it? It's just an integral though, and then an application of Stokes' theorem...

Comment: B. Conrad's (still unpublished?) book on Ramanujan's conjecture is a (the?) modern exposition on Deligne's 1969 Bourbaki talk. It has all detailed computations. Check Brian's webpage.